# How to remove this controller error from Odoo v10

Tags: python, web-services, controller, odoo, json-rpc

I have written a controller to push the data to the client-side. The code is below. Can anybody please mention what is the error in this? Because I'm getting error like

```
File "/home/user/odoo/odoo10/custom/project/project_custom/controllers/main.py", line 21, in post_api_method
    partners = request['import.order'].sudo().search_read([('customer', '=', 'TRADING COMPANY')])
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 373, in <lambda>
    __getitem__ = lambda x, i: x._get_current_object()[i]
TypeError: 'HttpRequest' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

My code is just below:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from odoo import http
import requests
import json
from odoo.http import request
from odoo import report as odoo_report
import datetime
import pytz
import base64
import logging

_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

url = 'https://*********/api/********logistics/fillshipmentdetails***'
authentication = '129487521452XSDFG156235C6B353CD75QWERBVFGHJAA96AA99EDSJUITH7AAF65258F22871E7D415EB4A77CF7B4CB513A993680FC6053EAE6RT785YUIJ124'

class MyApi(http.Controller):

    @http.route("/my/post/api/path", url=url, auth="none", type='http', method=['POST'], csrf=False, cors='*')
    def post_api_method(self, *kw):
        partners = request['import.order'].sudo().search_read([('customer', '=', 'TRADING COMPANY')])

        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        body = {'results': {"shipmentType": partners.ship_Type,
                            "shipperName": partners.customer.name,
                            "consigneeName": "*****",
                            "vslexparvlDate": "2019-03-05 05:55:13:000",
                            "vsldischlDate": "2019-04-02 05:55:13:000",
                            "docRecvByMailDate": "2019-03-05 05:55:13:000",
                            "orgDocRecvgDate": "2019-03-24 05:55:13:000",
                            "vesselArvlDate": "2019-03-19 05:55:13:000",
                            "bLAwbNumber": "*****",
                            "houseBL": "****",
                            "dischargingPort": "*****",
                            "landingPort": "*****",
                            "containerNumber": "*****",
                            "delOrderDate": "2019-03-29 05:55:13:000",
                            "delOrderNumber": "******",
                            "bayanNumber": "*****",
                            "bayanDate": "2019-03-30 05:55:13:000",
                            "containerType": "*****",
                            "dutyPaidDate": "2019-03-22 05:55:13:000",
                            "transportNTFTerminal": "***",
                            "transportDirCustomer": "***",
                            "demmurageDate": "2019-03-27 05:55:13:000",
                            "lastDetentionDate": "2019-03-27 05:55:13:000",
                            "eIRReturnToShipLine": "****",
                            "eventUpdateStatus": "Delivered"
                            }}
        response = requests.post(url, json.dumps(body), headers=headers)
        return response
```

All the values given to the keys are demo datas. First two key value is only the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access ORM models using the environment bound to the current request (`http.request.env`).

```
partners = request.env['import.order'].sudo().search_read([('customer', '=', 'TRADING COMPANY')])
```